# Jquery function doesn't work on partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm making a live search function using ajax on laravel 7 and it works just fine for the most part. However, i have a button that disables the functions of the search output. When the page first loaded the functions are successfully disabled. But when i run the live search, the output's function is enabled again. I'm guessing its because the live search output is taken from a partial view/html which then loaded to the main view/html. The function run without any problem just after the page loads because the DOM already loaded it. When i append a new view/html, the DOM doesn't recognize it.

Here is the ajax code

```
function fetch_data(page, query){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/search?query="+query+"&page="+page,
        success:function(data){
            $('#product-container').html('');
            $('#product-container').html(data);
        }
    });
}
$('#search').keyup(delay(function(){
    var query = $('#search').val();
    var page = $('#hidden_page').val();
    fetch_data(page, query);
}, 400));
```

This is the partial view

```
<div class="row">
  @if(count($products) < 1)
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <h5>No results</h5>
  </div>
  @endif
  @foreach($products as $product)
  <div class="col-md-3" id="item">
    <div class="product__item p-2" style="background: #dce0e2;">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/products/'. $product->image) }}">
      </div>
      <div class="product__item__text">
        <h6 style=" white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">{{ $product->name }}</h6>
        <h5>{{ rupiah($product->price) }}</h5>
      </div>
      <a href="{{ route('kasir.add.item', ['product_id' => $product->id]) }}" class="add-btn" id="{{ $product->id }}">
        <div class="btn-success text-center m-2 p-1">
          Add +
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
{{ $products->links('partials.pagination') }}
```

This is the controller

```
public function search(Request $request){
    if ($request->ajax()) {
      $query = $request->get('query');
      $query = str_replace(" ", "%", $query);
      $products = Product::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query."%")->paginate(8);
      return view('kasir.product_data', compact('products'))->render();
    }
  }
```

My question is can the DOM load the partial view as if it loaded at the same time as the page so that the jquery functions can work on the new view/html?

Comment: If you are trying to add an event listener to newly added elements you have to do so after they have been added or use event delegation

Comment: @Patrick Evans I'm sorry i don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: What @PatrickEvans means is that the moment the page is loaded, the listeners are added to the DOM elements. If you dynamically add new content and you want listeners on them too, this won't work. You can circumvent this with adding jQuery to the partial you are adding. Not the function, obviously. `$('#search').keyup(...)` creates a listener. Add the same code to the partials at the bottom of the blade page. Don't push it, just add it. I've done this many times. Because it's JavaScript, it doesn't create a paradox. If may only look a bit weird if you ask for the generated source.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your partial (only works if you add it through ajax requests). It will add the listeners you want, even after the DOM is completely loaded the first time. Rerunning the same piece of jQuery will re-establish the listeners you are expecting.

```
<div class="row">
  ....
</div>
{{ $products->links('partials.pagination') }}

<script>
$('#search').keyup(delay(function(){
var query = $('#search').val();
var page = $('#hidden_page').val();
    fetch_data(page, query);
}, 400));
</script>
```